# Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() while open

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` in my WinForm application to get the parameters input by the user. Works well as it should do. Though as it is a single instance application I'd like the application to receive these parameters even when it is opened.

So, can a a single instance application get these parameters while it is open?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startupnextinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For those who have never used the Startup() or StartupNextInstance() events suggested by Hans Passant in the comments above:

1. In Project --> Properties, Application Tab.
2. Click on the Button labeled "View Application Events" in the very bottom
   right (scroll down).
3. In the left dropdown at the top, change it from "(General)" to
   "(MyApplication Events)".
4. In the right dropdown at the top, select "Startup" or
   "StartupNextInstance".

[image: Adding the StartupNextInstance() Event]

Here is what the code editor window looks like after both the Startup() and StartupNextInstance() events were added:

```
Namespace My

    ' The following events are available for MyApplication:
    ' 
    ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
    ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
    ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
    ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
    ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

        End Sub

        Private Sub MyApplication_StartupNextInstance(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.StartupNextInstanceEventArgs) Handles Me.StartupNextInstance

        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```